# How do I use the Platform module to make sure I use the correct Picker version in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, behavior, picker

I've written most of my code for android.  One of the components contains a picker item that allows the user to choose between two different countries.  The android version of this works with no issues.  However, when I tried it on the IOS, it's unusuable.  That's when I realized PickerIOS is available.

What I would like to do, is use Platform to determine which OS is being used and then use the appropriate picker.  For example

```
  <KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.pickerView}
                        behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? PickerIos: Picker}
                    >
                        <Picker>
                            <Picker.Item label='france' value='france'/>
                            <Picker.Item label='england' value='england'/>
                        </Picker>

                        <PickerIOS>
                            <PickerIOS.Item label='france' value='france'/>
                            <PickerIOS.Item label='england' value='england'/>
                        </PickerIOS>

                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

I've purposely use KeyboardAvoidingView because it's one of the few components I know uses the 'behavior' attribute.  However, I'm quite sure that I can't leave it the way it currently is.  How do I make sure that the correct picker is used?

Would it be better to use a function to render the picker according the current OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would recommend to use a function. For example you could do the following:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.pickerView}
{this.choosePicker()}
</KeyboardAvoidingView>


choosePicker() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') { 
        return (
            <PickerIOS>
                <PickerIOS.Item label='france' value='france'/>
                <PickerIOS.Item label='england' value='england'/>
            </PickerIOS>
        );
    } 
    // if Platform is not ios return other Picker
    return (
        <Picker>
            <Picker.Item label='france' value='france'/>
            <Picker.Item label='england' value='england'/>
        </Picker>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Sorry about the delayed response.

Comment: @VK1 you're welcome! If my answer has helped you, please mark it as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use platform specific picker like this :---

```
const MyPicker = Platform.select({
    ios: PickerIOS,
    android: Picker
});

render() {
    return (
        <MyPicker>
            <MyPicker.Item label='france' value='france'/>
            <MyPicker.Item label='england' value='england'/>
        </MyPicker>
    );
}
```